# What API could be used to sync an Android app with a Windows application

Tags: android, windows

I want to write an application on both Android and Windows that behaves somewhat like dropbox or evernote. The functionality that I need to implement basically allows someone to upload data from an Android app and updates a remote user running said Windows application. Here's a simple use case/example:

1. The mobile device user uses said Android app to indicate his/her global positioning coordinates.
2. Those coordinates are sent to a server somewhere by the Android app.
3. The server updates registered Windows client applications, stating that new coordinates have been submitted by a mobile device user.
4. The Windows client application can then view those coordinates on a map.

More to the point, the idea is to implement some functionality where a mobile device user can submit data and have that data accessible by some kind of remote control center that runs Windows. Also please refrain from mentioning a GPS-specific API as the example I have mentioned is only that, an example.

Many Thanks!